# How to get numbers between a long space (PHP Regex)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'd like to extract the numbers specifically with a PHP regex expression, I don't get the regex very much although I'm currently trying with the regex101 website. Thing is, I have this:

```
66
                              28006 MadridVer teléfono
```

(Literally that, it's seen with a lot of more spaces and 28006 MadridVer teléfono is presented in the next line actually). And I'd like to extract the number 28006 or at least split the findings of the expression in a way I have the 28006 separately in one of the groups. What would be my php regex expresion like? Maybe apart from capturing spaces I should capture a new line or something. But I am totally lost in this (yes, I'm an absolute regex novice yet).

Comment: Do you mean matching only 1 number and there should be whitespace characters from the start of the string? https://3v4l.org/8Leku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need for regex.

Remove the new line and explode on space.
Then use array_filter to remove empty values from the array and rearrange the array with array_values.

```
$str = "66
                              28006 MadridVer teléfono";

$str = str_replace("\n", " ", $str);
$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$arr = array_values(array_filter($arr));
var_dump($arr);
```

Returns:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "66"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "28006"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "MadridVer"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "teléfono"
}
```